# The diophantine equation $\dfrac1a=\dfrac{1}{x_1}+\dfrac{1}{x_2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{x_n}$ for arbitrary integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

NOTE.- Looking for information on Egyptian fractions, I find that, contrary to what I believed, this interesting property of unit fractions has already been established previously. So I edit this post giving the easy solution before deleting it tomorrow.

We consider the diophantine equation $$\dfrac1a = \dfrac{1}{x_1} + .... + \dfrac{1}{ x_n}\tag 1$$  A trivial solution comes from $\dfrac1a=\dfrac{n}{na}$ but finding a non-trivial solution could be very difficult even when $n$ is small. However, there is a very easy deductible way that leads us to state the following problem:

Let $a$ and $n$ be arbitrary positive integers. Prove that equation $(1)$ has at least $n-1$ non-trivial solutions $(a_1, ...., a_n)\in\mathbb N^n$.

**Solution**.- We have the identity $\dfrac{1}{a}=\dfrac{1}{a+1}+\dfrac{1}{a(a+1)}$ .
By iteration there are 2 distinct ways to solve the equation for three unit fractions, 3 ways for four, 4 ways for five and so on.

Comment: Can you find **one** solution? What about two solutions? From there, finding $n-1$ solutions is probably not that difficult.

Comment: @Arthur.- Give me a pair $a,n$ (obviously not $n$ big) and I give you a solution. I repeat, the problem is elementary.

Comment: You seem quite certain you can find a solution no matter what $a$ and $n$ are. How exactly would you do that? Can you describe an approach without actually knowing $a$ and $n$ beforehand? You do that, and you are very close to an answer to your problem.

Comment: @Piquito What did you try, where are you stuck ?

Comment: @Arthur.- Yes, absolutely yes. If you give me, for example $(a,n)=(7,5)$ you can write    $$\frac17=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{57}+\frac{1}{73}+\frac{1}{3192}+\frac{1}{5256}$$

Comment: @The Silver Doe.- I am not stuck and sure my problem is easy to solve. That is why I have proposed it here.

Comment: This is not a place to suggest problems you know the answer to.

Comment: @kp9r4d That is just flatly untrue. For instance, on the page where you would compose your question post, it gives you the option to "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style". So this is very much a site where you can do that, and you are even explicitly encouraged to do so. It would be nice to point that out in the question post, though, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: @kp9r4d.-I think the downvotes for this post are totally unjustified. I will not erase it until they accumulate as much as those who cannot solve it want. In the meantime, I am waiting for a likely answer from a teenage student who can see how easy it is.

Comment: What is the point of this question?

Comment: @Piquito I downvoted. In my opinion, you can post questions you know the answer iff you think the problem is really interesting (for example, if you want to share an unknown method or to enlight a specific point of view). Here obviously, it is not the case : your question is very easy and every teenage student, as you said, can solve it.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe.- If you have no sensitivity to the exposed property, then act as you want unjustifiably with your downvote. I do feel the beauty of that property of the reciprocals of integers and that is why I wanted to share it with other people.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Whether a problem is interesting is really not a question of its level, or how difficult you find it. This site is explicitly stated to be for _all_ levels. I think this problem is cool, if a bit unrefined in its presentation.

Comment: @Arthur.- Thank you very much. You have understood the essentials of the situation. It is very true about the deficient language but the fact is that without the Google translator I could neither solve nor propose problems in MSE. I only speak Spanish and French.

Comment: @Arthur It is not a question of level or difficulty : you are right, a problem can be very easy and have a really interesting and deep solution, or be very beautiful, as Piquito says. In that case, it would be justified to post it on the site knowing the answer. I just find that this is not the case for this particular problem, which (in my opinion) brings nothing interesting. If someone posts "I know the answer but please prove that for all $x$, one has $x^2+2 \geq \cos(x)$", you will undoubtedly think that it has not its place here. I feel the same with this question.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I agree with the trig question. But I believe that this problem is qualitatively different. Other than "it's not a standard school algebra problem, you actually have to think a little outside the box" I couldn't tell you why, though. It is a very standard competition type problem, though. Maybe I'm just a sucker for those.

Comment: @Arthur Well, everyone has his opinion ;) I just downvoted, and I explain why (which is better, I think, than downvoting without explanation). I don't want to discourage anyone to think about the question.

Comment: @Arthur.- Dear friend, I think, perhaps exaggerating, that this beautiful result should be taught to first-level children, as a nice property of integers (the most elusive of mathematical objects according to the well-known British mathematician J.W.S. Cassels). I give you (and other people who read this comment) the easy key to the solution: it is enough to solve for $n = 2$ and the rest comes out immediately (surely you realize why).

Comment: @Piquito The fact that $1/a = 1/(2a) + 1/(2a)$ *is not* a "beautiful result" nor a "nice property of integers"...

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works, but obviously, there are in general much more than $n-1$ solutions to your equation. As TheSilverDoe's pointed in the comment, you can generate a lot of solutions just using the property that $$1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$$

Here's a sketch on how to find easily a lot a solutions. First note that the $a$ is useless : indeed, if you can prove the property for $a=1$, then multiplying all the $x_i$'s by $a$, you get the property for $a$. So it is enough to prove it for $a=1$.

For $n=2$, you have the obvious decomposition $$1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$$
and for $n=3$, you have the two decompositions $$1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}$$

Now, let me explain how you can generate a lot of solution, by induction. If you have a certain solution for $n$, let's say that
$$1 = \frac{1}{x_1} + ... + \frac{1}{x_n}$$

you have to ways to generate a solution for $n+1$. The first one is two divide one of the term in two equal parts (so you can generate $n$ new solutions, even if they can be the same) :

$$1 = \frac{1}{x_1} + ...+ \frac{1}{2x_i}+\frac{1}{2x_i}+ ... + \frac{1}{x_n}$$

The second one is to divide **all** the terms by $2$, writing
$$1 = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2x_1} +  ... + \frac{1}{2x_n}$$

You can check that this algorithm lets us construct a very high number of solutions, and can answer your original question. Moreover, if I come back to the original problem with the $a$, all the solutions constructed this way involve only multiples of $a$ (whereas your solution does not involve necessarily multiples of $a$) : that means that there are much more solutions than the one you constructed.

Asking *exactly*  (or estimate precisely) how many solutions the equation has could be an much more interesting problem, in my opinion.

Comment: According to what I said in the post yesterday, I thought about deleting this today but the existence of an answer (yours, somewhat naive I think) prevents me from doing so by rules prevailing in MSE. I'm sorry, I would like to erase it for being so badly interpreted by some people.

Comment: Why deleting ? Your original question is not interesting (that's why it has been poorely received, I guess), but I would say that the question of estimating the number of solutions to the equation can be very interesting and far more difficult. In my opinion, leaving this question open is a good thing, if people want to give some thoughts.

Comment: Think as you see fit, dear friend.